# Android Room with Dagger 2 in a multi-module

Tags: android, android-room, dagger, multi-module, android-multi-module

Is there a way or approach to provide a Room DB instance from a module/library which can be consume on any project (app module)?

The problem I am facing is the abstract class that extends `RoomDatabase()` lies in our app module and there we define our entities using `@Database` annotation. This is the reason I cannot provide a Room instance coming from a module other than app module since creating Room instance requires you to define the app database class that extends the `RoomDataBase()`.

Example in my `:app:libs:common` module. This is a submodule, it has its own repository which can be use for any project. The `appName` is provided in the `AppModule` which resides in app module itself and it is working with SharedPreferences that I made.

```
 @Module
 CommonModule {
    
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedPreferencesInstance(
        @Named("AppName") appName: String,
        application: Application
    ): SharedPreferences {
        application.apply {
            return getSharedPreferences(appName, MODE_PRIVATE)
        }
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppSharedPrefImplInstance(
        sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    ): SharedPref = SharedPrefImpl(sharedPreferences)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRoomDatabaseInstance(
            application: Application,
            @Named("AppName") appName: String,
            @Named("AppDatabase") roomDatabase: RoomDatabase
        ): RoomDatabase {
            return Room
                .databaseBuilder(application, roomDatabase.javaClass, appName)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
        }
    
}
```

This is the app module.

```
@Module
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("AppName")
    fun provideAppName(application: Application): String {
        application.apply {
            return getString(R.string.app_name)
        }
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAssetDao(@Named("AppDatabase") db: AppDatabase): AssetDao {
        return db.assetDao
    }
}
```

Since we use abstract class when extending `RoomDatabase()` in this case it's `AppDatabase` I tried to use `@Binds` in hope that it will work.

```
@Module
abstract class RoomModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    @Named("AppDatabase")
    abstract fun bindAppDatabase(appDatabase: AppDatabase): AppDatabase

}
```

I think being able to provide the AppDatabase class via generic on common module will allow me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this case.
I have written a boilerplate for using multiple modules in an Android project, it contains the room database.
You can refer to my repos
[My Repo](https://github.com/namlxcntt/AndroidCleanArchitecture-NoteApp)

Hope this is helpful to you

Comment: Thanks but I don't think we have the same scenario, what I am trying to achieve is putting `Room.databaseBuilder` in another module (common) not in the app module.

Comment: You can add to module (common) and build aar file and import to app module.